# Slideshow con Javascript, anterior y siguiente y miniaturas (paginación)

Tags: javascript

Cómo hago que dependiendo qué `figure class="tv-item-preview"` se clicke, vaya a esa "diapositiva". Creo que es ejecutando `function goToSlide(n)` pero no sé cómo hacer que identifique el `(n)` con el número de `tv-item-preview` que se ha hecho click.

También me gustaría que dependiendo si está a la derecha o a la izquierda del `current` aplicarle una animación en CSS u otra.

¿Es mejor usar Javascript o jQuery? Ahora que aún estoy a tiempo de cambiarlo.

Creo que es bastante fácil, pero no sé hacerlo... Gracias.

```
    <section>
        <div class="tv-item-wrap">
            <div class="item-nav-wrap">
                <nav class="nav-roundslide">
                    <a id="prev" class="prev" href="#">
                        <h3>Anterior</h3>
                    </a>
                    <a id="next" class="next" href="#">
                        <h3>Siguiente</h3>
                    </a>
                </nav>
            </div>


            <div id="tv-item-placeholder" class="tv-item-placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li class="tv-item tv-1 showing">
                        <div class="tv-item-content">
                            <h2>TV 1</h2>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="tv-item tv-2">
                        <div class="tv-item-content">
                            <h2>TV 2</h2>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="tv-item tv-3">
                        <div class="tv-item-content">
                            <h2>TV 3</h2>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="tv-item-prev-wrap">
        <div class="tv-item-preview-block">
            <div>
                <figure class="tv-item-preview current-preview">
                    <img src="img/video-previews/1.jpg" alt=""/>    
                </figure>
                <figure class="tv-item-preview">
                    <img src="img/video-previews/2.jpg" alt=""/>    
                </figure>
                <figure class="tv-item-preview">
                    <img src="img/video-previews/3.jpg" alt=""/>    
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Y el JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.tv-item');
    var currentSlide = 0;
    var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,8000);
    var slidesPreview = document.querySelectorAll('.tv-item-preview')

    function nextSlide(){
        goToSlide(currentSlide+1);}

    function previousSlide(){
        goToSlide(currentSlide-1);}

    function goToSlide(n){
        slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("showing");
        slidesPreview[currentSlide].classList.remove("current-preview");
        currentSlide = (n+slides.length)%slides.length;
        slides[currentSlide].classList.add("showing");
        slidesPreview[currentSlide].classList.add("current-preview");
    }

    var next = document.getElementById('next');
    var previous = document.getElementById('prev');

    slidesPreview.onclick = function goToSlide(n){};

    next.onclick = function(){
        nextSlide();};
    previous.onclick = function(){
        previousSlide();};

</script>
```

Comment: Tienes el resto del código en algún sitio? Alguna forma de que se pueda probar todo?